# Add Dependency to module - External Library Error

Tags: android, build.gradle

I've created an external library that I was hoping to make open source. I import it as a module without issue.

I have to resolve this issue after import:
[image]

Adding the dependency is what I want to do. I don't want to move it to :app.

When I add the dependency, the issue goes away. The import references the correct file. On build I get this issue:
[image]

I figure the solution has to be with referencing the java file in the build.gradle file for the external library but I couldnt find any good examples or even proof that this would resolve the issue.

library is the module name.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
build.gradle for the app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.weaverprojects.toundertest1"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
}
```

build.gradle for library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
  dependencies {
  //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
 }
```

Settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

Comment: can you post the relevent parts of your build.gradle and settings.gradle

Comment: Please look up this one I hope it will helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your *library* exists as it's own project, and it'd path relative to the top level folder for your *main* project is ../mylibs/library/ I think your settings.gradle should change as follows:

```
project(':library').projectDir = new File('../mylibs/library/');
```

and the following needs to go inside the dependencies section of your *main*/app/build.gradle file (which I think is the first code dump in your question).

```
compile project(':library')
```

BTW, please consider renaming :library to something else (this is not the source of the problem but the name can be confusing when you look at it some months later)